# Shape for popup in qml

Tags: qt, popup, qml

I want to create a popup as the root element and the shape of the popup is shown in the image(i.e. small triangle shape)

[image: Popup with small triangle shape i.e. indicating the direction of the item that is the placement target]

Do qml have any property where i can define this shape (if yes then how).
If no then what is the best way to customize the shape of the popup.
Also is it possible to use delegate and model property for popup (if yes then how)?

Comment: Please, try to restrain to one topic at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a `Popup` a background:

```
Popup {
    background: Canvas {
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.fillStyle = "white"
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(0,10)
            ctx.lineTo(width * 0,5 - 10, 10)
            ctx.lineTo(width * 0,5, 0)
            ctx.lineTo(width * 0,5 + 10, 10)
            ctx.lineTo(width, 10)
            ctx.lineTo(width, height)
            ctx.lineTo(0, height)
            ctx.closePath()
            ctx.fill()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Popup::background is the exact right answer and this is a very nice solution. You could also use a Rectangle with border radius and with another small child Rectangle rotated 45 degrees and placed at the top center.

Comment: haha, great idea to use two Rectangles :-D might be more performant. I took this from own codes where I have a Rectangle with one corner cut off, so that's why I started with a Canvas

Comment: Child Rectangles are also a great way to get border radius on only certain corners of a parent Rectangle.

Comment: Used a rectangle and rotated it.                                                  Rectangle
        {
            id: triangleShape
            width: 10
            height: 10
            color: "black"
            rotation: 135
        }